# how to get the spark broadcast variable in the executor? spark-core

Tags: apache-spark, task, broadcast, executor

here, I have one app which has two jobs. And in the first job, i want to set the broadcast such as setting the broadcast variable "true", accessing the broadcast in the executor. and in the second job, i want to set the broadcast variable "false". and How to achieve the requirement?
my code is:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)     
var setCapture = true
sc.broadcast(setCapture)
val file = lc.textFile("file" ,2)
val flatMap = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
val report = counts.collect()
setCapture = false
sc.broadcast(setCapture)
val packageResult = sc.parallelize(report).filter(_._1 == "package")
packageResult.collect.foreach(println)
```

and I want to access the broadcast variable  " **setCapture** " in the

**org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask**,

**org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD**,

**org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap**,

**org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleWriter**.

What should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the spark broadcast variable in the executor? spark-core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316635/how-to-get-the-spark-broadcast-variable-in-the-executor-spark-core)

Comment: sorry ,the previous has no code ,

Comment: Then close the previous post

Comment: how do I delete the previous one.

Comment: You can see it -> http://awesomescreenshot.com/06e5vshp21

Comment: I'm sorry, but you really need to be more clear. The last part of your post makes no sense to me. You write _" I want to access the broadcast variable 'setCapture' in the..."_ and then you put something that looks like part of a stacktrace. What part of your code is not working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Spark documentation

> Broadcast variables are created from a variable v by calling SparkContext.broadcast(v). The broadcast variable is a wrapper around v, and its value can be accessed by calling the value method. The code below shows this:

```
scala> val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(Array(1, 2, 3)) 
broadcastVar: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Array[Int]] = Broadcast(0)

scala> broadcastVar.value
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

> After the broadcast variable is created, it should be used instead of the value v in any functions run on the cluster so that v is not shipped to the nodes more than once. In addition, the object v should not be modified after it is broadcast in order to ensure that all nodes get the same value of the broadcast variable (e.g. if the variable is shipped to a new node later).

Comment: I guess then question is how to read the value from the broadcasted variable in a function that has no access to the broadcast object or the spark context.